# Returning an int from a single row in a Sqlite DB

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo

I need to return 2 ints that are from a DB, but, I can't seem to get the query right.

```
$result1 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM StoredData WHERE VoteName="foo"')->fetch(); 
$result2 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM StoredData WHERE VoteName="bar"')->fetch();
```

I need result 1/2 to return ints from the column named "VoteTotal", I have tried various things without much luck, including changing the * to just VoteTotal which I thought would do it.

The VoteName is unique, I've also tried fetchcolumn without any luck :(

Schema is simply:

ID, VoteName, VoteTotal

Comment: Maybe you need to use single quotes in your query?

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing 'VoteName' as static value then do not use quotes at all, like below.

```
$result1 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM StoredData WHERE VoteName=foo')->fetch(); 
$result2 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM StoredData WHERE VoteName=bar')->fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like was explained before you have to avoid using quotes if it is a static value or put the variable directly without quotes as $variable_name.
Making * to VoteTotal should do the trick.

Else you will have an associative array from which you will have to select the required result using $result["VoteTotal"]

```
$result1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM StoredData WHERE VoteName=foo")->VoteTotal;
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code you gave us, variable $result1 (and $result2) are rows from your database.
What you were lacking is to select wanted column with **['VoteTotal']**.
This is code that worked for me:

```
$connection = new PDO("mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost;charset=utf8", "admin", "admin");
$connection -> exec("set names utf8");

$name1 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM storedata WHERE VoteName='name1'");
$name2 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM storedata WHERE VoteName='name2'");

echo $name1->fetch()['VoteName'];
echo "<br><br>";
echo $name2->fetch()['VoteTotal'];
```

Hope it helps.